# Query multiple AWS regions for active EC2 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

Can we query multiple AWS regions at the same time?.

I want to query for data from multiple AWS regions through AWS CLI, for example, all the EC2 instances active in every region.

Answer (score 8):

No there is no way to set multiple regions in one setting. You could do something like this

```
for region in `aws ec2 describe-regions --output text | cut -f3`
do
     echo -e "\nListing Instances in region:'$region'..."
     aws ec2 describe-instances --region $region
done
```

Comment: maybe the command output has changed now, but as of this writing, it should be `... | cut -f4`