# AWS get list of all resources containing certain string?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Is there a way to get a list of all resources in an account across all regions containing a certain string in the name? For example all resources which contains `hyd` string in it's name. :  `*-hyd-*-*`. Generally tag editor will be used for tags but i am not looking for tags. Thank you for the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this thread:
[Query multiple AWS regions for active EC2 instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43984337/query-multiple-aws-regions-for-active-ec2-instances/43984651#43984651)

or this thread:
[Is there a way to list all resources in AWS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44391817/is-there-a-way-to-list-all-resources-in-aws?rq=2)

Would comment but still ain't 50 rep ;D Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Tag editor was the way to go eventually. All i had to do was look up the resources and then use the string to filter resources.